# civic elements - meaning

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/monkey-cage/wp/2014/09/26/the-kremlin-doesnt-have-a-blank-check-from-russians-for-its-ukraine-policy/

> This development does not necessarily mean that **civic elements** of Russian national identity are more salient than ethno-cultural ones.  A majority of Russians have long supported, in some variant, the idea of “Russia for [ethnic] Russians.”

I don't understand what "civic elements of Russian national identity" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiktionary definces *[civic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/civic)* as

> Of or relating to the citizen, or of good citizenship and its rights and duties.

Thus, a civic person is a person who cares more about his compatriots' rights and duties as co-citizens than about their nationality or some other trait.

*Russian national identity* is a vague term. I'd put it as "how Russians view themselves". Do they view themselves as citizens of a multinational country where all nations are equal? If they have such visions, express such views, that would count for "*civic elements*". When only a minority of the population expresses such views, that would mean some other idea has become more *salient*.

The idea of "Russia for ethnic Russians" would clash with the *civic* view because one would have to infringe on other persons' rights to keep Russia ethnically uniform. Not to mention the [fatuity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fatuity) of such an idea in a country where [ethnic groups count in hundreds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_groups_in_Russia).